# sum function and differential equation

Tags: real-analysis

I have this sum function: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3^n)(x^{2n})}{7^{n+1}}$

And I have to show that it solves this differential equation:
$(7-3x^2)y' - 6xf=0$

Can anyone please help.

Comment: We call sum functions series. To get you started, assumed that $y = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, find an expression for $y'$, and substitute that into your equation. Then try to solve for $a_n$. Also, should $f$ be $y$ in your question?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
y&=\sum_{n=0}\dfrac{3^{n}}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n}\\
y'&=\sum_{n=1}\dfrac{2\cdot 3^{n}n}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n-1}\\
-3x^{2}y'&=\sum_{n=1}\dfrac{-6\cdot 3^{n}n}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n+1}\\
(7-3x^{2})y'&=\dfrac{6}{7}x+\sum_{n=1}\dfrac{2\cdot 3^{n+1}(n+1)}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n+1}-\sum_{n=1}\dfrac{6\cdot 3^{n}n}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{6}{7}x+\sum_{n=1}\left(\dfrac{2\cdot 3^{n+1}(n+1)}{7^{n+1}}-\dfrac{6\cdot 3^{n}n}{7^{n+1}}\right)x^{2n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{6}{7}x+\sum_{n=1}\dfrac{6\cdot 3^{n}n+6\cdot 3^{n}-6\cdot 3^{n}n}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{6}{7}x+\sum_{n=1}\dfrac{6\cdot 3^{n}}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}\dfrac{6\cdot 3^{n}}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n+1}\\
-6xy&=\sum_{n=0}\dfrac{-6\cdot 3^{n}}{7^{n+1}}x^{2n+1}\\
(7-3x^{2})y'-6xy&=0.
\end{align*}